# which file to specify during the git pull

Tags: git, version-control

I have very less experience with 'git'. There is a sub-directory in a git repository,
and I want to `pull` that sub directory, but in the command 
`git pull <file-name>`, which file name should I specify. I do not see any `.git` file in the directory.

Comment: Is that directory a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve just a subfolder of a git repository - you always need to `git clone` the whole repository.

Whoever told you that you can `git pull <filename>` told you something wrong. The syntax of `git pull` is:

```
git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I want to pull the whole repository, where can i find the '.git' file that should be specified in the command `git pull <filename.git>`

Comment: You clone a repository with `git clone <original> <clone>`.  This creates a new local repository named <clone>.  After commits are made to the original, type `git pull` from anywhere in the clone to retrieve them.  The filename.git reference is only used to identify remote repositories, accessed with http(s) or ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Git is not like svn.

One possible way to achieve something similar would be to have that directory as a different git repository and use it as a git submodule on both repositories.

Take a look on this part of the git book for more info:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules